# get ajax output from filled var and print out while loading the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I created this ajax file. I just want to know if there is a way to load the ajax file before i type in something. This file is only to test the ajax. When u run it the html display only the search bar. if i type something it print the typed stuff of the search bar and the var second. But i want that the html file displays it from beginning and the var will change later in the final file. is there a way to run the ajax once when I open up the page and not when i start typing?

I want to print the saved var(in this case second) when i open up the page or press f5. So when i open up the page it should print out: abcd

because the variable already exist(again it is var second)

I want that the function 'keyup(function()' run on beginning to show the results of the hardcoded string

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="search_text">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search_text").keyup(function(){
            var search = $(this).val();
            var second = "abcd";
            $.ajax({
                url:'checkvalues.php',
                method:'post',
                data:{query:search, second:second},
                success: function(resonse){
                    $("#result").html(resonse);

                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
    echo $_POST['query'];
}
if(isset($_POST['second'])){
    echo $_POST['second'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run something "immediately" in your case you can just run it in a function passed as an argument of `ready` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //everything here is ran just after the event fired
        //so you can just call AJAX
        $.ajax({});
        //or create separated function doing it and then call it
        myFuncCallingAJAX();
})
```

Comment: you missunderstood me. the ajax file is working but the output isnt visible before i type a letter into the search box

Comment: @frederik you asked _"is there a way to run the ajax once when I open up the page and not when i start typing"_ ...this answer shows you how to do that. It precisely answers the question you asked. If you really meant something different you'll need to update your question and make it a lot clearer, maybe with an example of what you are talking about. You also said _"i want that the html file displays it from beginning"_ but it's far from clear what "it" actually is. Your AJAX call responds to someone typing. If you run it before they've typed anything, what precisely do you want it to show?

Comment: i want to know how i can call a resonse for every var i included. In this example i want the response from `var second = "abcd";`

Comment: @frederik but what is `second` var? `search` is pretty clear, the value of the input field. But what is second. You say you want to execute for every var, but it's hard to understand what do you mean by this. Actually your var `second` is hardcoded string 'abcd'.

Comment: @frederik I think you want to know how to echo all the values in your PHP response? It depends how you want to receive it afterwards. You can either make them into one string e.g. `<?php $output = "";
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
    $output .= $_POST['query'];
}
if(isset($_POST['second'])){
    $output .= $_POST['second'];
} echo $output;
?>` ...

Comment: @frederik ...cont'd: or you can put them into an object and echo as JSON with two separate properties. e.g. `<?php $output = array();
if(isset($_POST['query'])){
    output["query"] = $_POST['query'];
}
if(isset($_POST['second'])){
    $output["second"] = $_POST['second'];
} echo json_encode($output);
?>` . Like I said it depends what you actually want to do with the result. In your current AJAX "success" you are just outputting the whole thing to a single HTML field, so maybe my first option suits you. Also...this output idea has nothing to do with running when you open the page??

Comment: no i want to know how to get the output directly on the start. So when i start typing into search it shows the result for search and second, but i want that i get output of second before i strart typing into search

Comment: @frederik is the "second" always hard-coded like in your question, or is that just an example?

Comment: @frederik so move your AJAX call to a separated function and then call it once manually with `second` var and then on every keyup event.